# How can we replace value of hive variables to check for any errors

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

We have a query in which we have defined more than 50 variables.

we call this hql via shell script, most of the times i get into syntax issue where i have not defined hive variables properly in the query.

```
Example
set hive var0=value0;
set hive var1=value1;
set hive var2=value2;

select * from ${hiveconf:var0} where col1=${hiveconf:var1} and col2=${hiveconf:var2};
```

I want to to check the above query result after replacing hive variables,
So is there a way to check if the variables are parsed in the right way or are there any syntax errors.

Please let me know for any alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better use `hivevar` namespace for the same.

You can print all variable using `! echo` command:

```
set hivevar:var0=value0;
hive> ! echo  Variable hivevar:var0 is ${hivevar:var0};
```

Result:

```
Variable hivevar:var0 is value0
```

Also use `explain extended <query>` - it will print detailed query plan with predicates and fail if it is syntax error.

Update:
Also you can use SELECT for doing the same and Hive can execute simple queries without MR started if `hive.fetch.task.conversion` is set to `more` or `minimal`. If you are using Qubole, add also `limit 1` to the query:

```
 set hive.fetch.task.conversion=more; 
 select 'Variable hivevar:var0 is', '${hivevar:var0}' limit 1;
```

Why you may need to do this using SELECT? For example for easy checking parameter using casting or some UDF. If you need to check if parameter is of type `DATE`, use

```
 set hive.fetch.task.conversion=more; 
 select 'Variable hivevar:var0 is', date '${hivevar:var0}' limit 1;
```

In this case if `${hivevar:var0}` is not date, then type cast exception will be thrown and script execution terminated.

Answer (score 1):

along with hivevar namespace, we can use one more property hive.root.logger=INFO,console.

this will display the query after replacing the variable value, from which we can find out the issue.

```
 cat test.hql
set hivevar:var1=${hivevar:var11};
set hivevar:var2=2345;

select ${hivevar:var11};
select ${hivevar:var2};
```

hive command - `hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=INFO,console --hivevar var11=1234 -f test.hql`

output on console

```
select 1234
2018-10-17T08:23:31,632  INFO [main] ql.Driver: Completed executing command(queryId=-4dd6-493f-88be-03810f847fe7); Time taken: 0.003 seconds
OK
2018-10-17T08:23:31,632  INFO [main] ql.Driver: OK
2018-10-17T08:23:31,670  INFO [main] io.NullRowsInputFormat$NullRowsRecordReader: Using null rows input format
1234
```